# why does this HttpClient PutAsync returns internal server error after a successful update

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient, internal-server-error

I have a HttpPut API method that edits an object it is passed and saves into the database successfully. This works fine, however from my MVC application, the httpClient.PutAsync which I use to call my API Put method returns internal server error, even though the API Put method does not.

I am not sure what is going wrong, the API method works fine, but somehow the MVC HttpClient still gets an internal server error.

**API PUT METHOD**

```
    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult Put([FromBody] School school)
    {
        try
        {
            var schoolExists = _schoolRepository.SchoolExists(school.Id);

            if (!schoolExists) return NotFound();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest();

            var schoolData = Mapper.Map<School, Data.School>(school);

            var updatedClass = _schoolRepository.UpdateSchool(schoolData);

            if (!updatedClass) return Json(GetHttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));

            var route = CreatedAtRoute("GetSchool", school);

            return route;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return LogException(e);
        }
    }
```

The method above works fine and my changes are saved into the database and CreatedAtRouteResult object is returned from the API method.

**MVC HTTPCLIENT**

```
    public async Task<T> PutObject(string path, T content, string accessToken)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                SetBaseUri(httpClient, accessToken);

                var serialisezContent = CreateHttpContent(content);

                var httpResponse = await httpClient.PutAsync(path, serialisezContent);

                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) throw new Exception("Problem accessing the api");

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(GetResult(httpResponse));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

    }
```

The method above is where is issue is, this line `var httpResponse = await httpClient.PutAsync(path, serialisezContent);` returns internal server error still. I have the same implementation for my POST and that works just fine.

**SETBASEURI()**

```
    private void SetBaseUri(HttpClient httpClient, string accessToken)
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUri);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            _authenticationHeaderValueCreator.CreateAuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
    }
```

**CreateHttpContent()**

```
    public ByteArrayContent CreateHttpContent<TParam>(TParam httpObject)
    {
        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(httpObject);
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);

        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        return byteContent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your API Put method indeed returns HTTP 500 error with message `No route matches the supplied values`. You could check it in Fiddler.

And the problem is with following line:

`var route = CreatedAtRoute("GetSchool", school);`

`CreatedAtRoute` method takes a route name as first argument. I doubt that you have a route named `GetSchool`. It's rather an action name in the same controller. And `CreatedAtRoute` will not throw exception for unknown route, it will just return 500 error code.

To fix this problem, use `CreatedAtAction` method instead of `CreatedAtRoute`:

```
var route = CreatedAtAction("GetSchool", school);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the result from the API is failing to serialize. Try to manually serialize the result yourself in a unit-test and see where it fails.